# Цикл не проходит все итерации с++

Tags: c++, циклы

нужно ввести N раз строки N-ого элемента массива в программе, но, когда нужно вводить последнюю строку, программа прерывается.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

enum clas {boec = 0, lekar = 1};

struct answer {
    string get;
    int lvl[];
    clas role;
    string name = " ";
};

main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    char ch;
    bool nameflag;
    answer arr[N];
    int k = 0;

    while( k < N ) {
        getline( cin, arr[k].get );
        k++;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for( int v = 0; v < arr[i].get.length(); v++ ) {
            ch = arr[i].get[v];
        }

        while( ch != '\n' ) {
            arr[i].get += ch;

            if( ch == '[' ) {
                nameflag = true;
                continue;
            }

            if( ch == ']' ) {
                nameflag = false;
                continue;
            }

            if( nameflag == true ) {
                arr[i].name += ch;
            }

            if( nameflag == false )   {
                int v = arr[i].get.find( "лекарь" );

                if( ( v == -1 ) ) {
                arr[i].role = boec;
                }
            }

            if( ch > '0' && ch <= '9' ) {
                static int l = 0;
                arr[i].lvl[l] = ch;
                l++;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваша программа некорректная и просто не имеет смысла.

Например, в объявлении структуры не может быть объявлений массивов без указания их размерности

```
struct answer {
    string get;
    int lvl[];
    ^^^^^^^^^
    clas role;
    string name = " ";
};
```

Стандартом C++ массивы переменной длины не поддерживаются. Поэтому данное объявление

```
int N;
cin >> N;
//...
answer arr[N];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

является некорректным с точки зрения языка C++. Хотя некоторые компиляторы имеют собственные расширения языка, которые позволяют определять массивы переменной длины, лучше не полагаться на такие расширения, так как код будет не переносим.

Вам  лучше было бы использовать стандартный контейнер `std::vector` вместо массива. Например,

```
std::vector<answer> arr;
```

Данный цикл

```
for( int v = 0; v < arr[i].get.length(); v++ ) {
    ch = arr[i].get[v];
}
```

бессмысленный. Он занесет в переменную `ch` значение последнего символа строки `arr[i].get`. Если вам действительно нужен только этот последний символ, то вы могли бы просто написать

```
ch = arr[i].get.back();
```

Имейте в виду, что строка может быть пустая, и тогда ваш цикл вообще не выполнится, а переменная `ch` будет иметь неопределенное значение.

Данное условие цикла

```
   while( ch != '\n' ) {
```

также бессмысленно, так как функция `getline` не записывает символ новой строки в строку. Поэтому совершенно не понятно, откуда в переменной `ch` может оказаться символ новой строки.

Поэтому будет лучше, если вы зададите новый вопрос, в котором опишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать, и какие проблемы при этом у вас возникают. А данный код совершенно никуда не годится.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выделяете статический массив размерностью N

```
answer arr[N];
```

Так как нумерация в массиве идет с **0**, то последний индекс массива, к которому вы можете обратиться, равен **N - 1**. Это последний индекс в массиве

Но в этом цикле

```
while( k <= N ) {
        getline( cin, arr[k].get );
        k++;
    }
```

будет обращение к элементу массива с индексом N, поэтому ваша программа падает.

Вы должны его переписать таким образом

```
while( k < N ) {
            getline( cin, arr[k].get );
            k++;
        }
```

И еще, в вашем примере кода есть такой код

```
if( nameflag == false )   {
                int v = arr[i].get.find( "лекарь" );

                if( ( v == -1 ) ) {
                arr[N].role = boec;
                }
            }
```

Здесь вы снова обращаетесь к массиву с индексом N, который вероятнее всего приведет к ошибке программы и ее аварийному завершению.

Кроме этого, если проанализировать логику вашей программы, то она зависнет в этом цикле `while( ch != '\n' )`, потому что символ перевода строки `'\n'` команда [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) не записывает в строку назначения. Она записывает в строку назначения символы до символа перевода строки. 
В коде я тоже не нашел явного явного присваивания этого символа. Поэтому будет бесконечный цикл у вас.

Comment: Исправил как вы говорили, но теперь, когда я ввожу последнюю (т.е. N ) строку, консоль зависает

Comment: А разве плюсы позволяют указывать в качестве размера статического массива переменные?

Comment: ошибки не выдает, да и к тому же вроде бы принимает строки, кроме последней

Comment: @topl3niy, обновил ответ

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков, да действительно, такой код не должен компилироваться.

Comment: и как же мне обозначить, что строка окончена?

Comment: @topl3niy, а зачем вам это обозначать? Вы имеете считанную строку, можете получить длину строки, последний символ в ней. Этого недостаточно будет для вашей логики?